# Casting to a ConstPtr object using const_cast

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, constants, point-cloud-library

Recently, I have come across a dilemma in my project.  I can either create a separate object of type pcl::PointCloud::ConstPtr and pass to it a point cloud that is identical to it except mutable, or I can try to cast the mutable point cloud to a ConstPtr point cloud.  I am trying to use const cast to cast the mutable point cloud to a format where it is accepted by several functions which only accept pointClouds which are ConstPtr's.  This is the cast I perform:

```
pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> rgbHandler(const_cast<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr >(&cloud));
```

but an error is thrown in terminal

```
error: const_cast to
      'pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr' (aka 'shared_ptr<const
      PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >'), which is not a reference,
      pointer-to-object, or pointer-to-data-member
  ...const_cast<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr >(&cloud));
```

which is strange because cloud is declared with a type of pcl::PointCloud here:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud;
```

So why doesn't this const cast work?  What would make it work?

Comment: A cast from a object reference (i.e. `&T`) to a smart pointer of the reference's type (i.e. `shared_ptr<T>`) is not defined. You'll need to construct the smart pointer.

Comment: You do not need any casts, pointer to non-const object can be passed to functions that expect pointer to const.